# kubectl cp: data lost?

Tags: kubernetes, centos, kubectl, kubernetes-pod

My file locally:

```
ls -al spark-streaming-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 me  110502799  137448102 Jan  2 16:59 spark-streaming-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

I used `kubectl cp` to copy this file to centOS pod in k8s, but I got

```
# ls -al examples/jars/spark-streaming-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
-rw------- 1 root root 110690304 Jan  2 22:15 examples/jars/spark-streaming-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

but 137448102 != 110690304. Any data lost?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

I did another `kubectl cp`, and put more details below:

On MAC:

```
me$ ls -al target/spark-streaming-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 me  110502799  137448102 Jan  2 17:24 target/spark-streaming-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
me$ md5 target/spark-streaming-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
MD5 (target/spark-streaming-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar) = ff6ae687b19c97871e65db6e4ea6002f
```

on CentOS POD of k8s:

```
root@myspark-master-5d6656bd84-79745:/usr/spark-2.3.1# ls -al examples/jars/spark-streaming-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
-rw------- 1 root root 132054528 Jan  2 22:47 examples/jars/spark-streaming-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
root@myspark-master-5d6656bd84-79745:/usr/spark-2.3.1# md5sum examples/jars/spark-streaming-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
edc4ddc8f011e5b8e79741e15ac1ac1d  examples/jars/spark-streaming-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

Comment: Why don't you use `sha256sum` or `md5sum` to verify integrity of the file? We're not seeing your cluster on Stack Overflow so we can't tell whether any data is lost or not. It's likely that the file size is pretty different.

Comment: @AhmetAlpBalkan-Google I updated my post

Comment: is `examples/jars/spark-streaming-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar` already in the pod prior to the `kubectl cp` command?

Comment: @Rico, I deleted it and then did copy...

Comment: Sounds interesting. I would try experimenting with normal text files that you can `diff` to see if it happens to other files too.

Comment: Looks like a bug if you can reproduce it with all kinds of different files.

Comment: This works for me for a 200m file `kubectl` and `kube-apiserver` `1.13.0`

Comment: If you have a Java jar file, usually you'd build that into a custom image and reference that from a pod spec in a deployment spec; you wouldn't manually `kubectl cp` it around.

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks. I am testing my spark job for now..

Comment: I also recommend using something like Skaffold (https://skaffold.dev/) and rebuilding a container on file change, instead of `kubectl cp`ing things around. I've been dealing with Kubernetes for 3 years, practically never heard of this command until yesterday.